# Show that 14 codewords define a $3-(8,4,1)$ design

Tags: coding-theory

I've recently read this paragraph of [this document (page 12)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1254.pdf):
[image]

I am able to compute these 14 codewords and verify that $A_4=14$. But then I don't get how this is a $3-(8,4,1)$ design, because I'm under the impression that I need a set $P=(1,...,8)$ and then I take some subsets size $4$ and check if any $3$ of these subsets are exactly in $1$ block?

So $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,2,6,7)$ are of this design? But I have $14$ codewords but my set should have $8$ so what do I have to do?

Comment: edited to include "design" instead of code. Please revert back if mistaken

Comment: The supports of those 14 codewords are **the blocks** of the design. Those supports are subsets of $P$ rather than the elements of $P$.